# Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and binary targets

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am trying to evaluate my xgboost model using `accuracy_score()`. And I have the code:

```
predictions = xgb_model.predict(X_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test.to_numpy(), predictions)
```

The error message looks like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [126], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test.to_numpy(), predictions)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:211, in accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize, sample_weight)
    145 """Accuracy classification score.
    146 
    147 In multilabel classification, this function computes subset accuracy:
   (...)
    207 0.5
    208 """
    210 # Compute accuracy for each possible representation
--> 211 y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    212 check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    213 if y_type.startswith("multilabel"):

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:93, in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     90     y_type = {"multiclass"}
     92 if len(y_type) > 1:
---> 93     raise ValueError(
     94         "Classification metrics can't handle a mix of {0} and {1} targets".format(
     95             type_true, type_pred
     96         )
     97     )
     99 # We can't have more than one value on y_type => The set is no more needed
    100 y_type = y_type.pop()

ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and binary targets
```

The parameters look like this

```
y_test.to_numpy()
```

[image]

```
predictions
```

[image]

They are all 1-d arrays and I cannot find where is the problem.
How should I calculate the accuracy score?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you cast it to int? e.g. `y_test.to_numpy().astype(int)` ?